# Csv file writing the extra rows while downloading

Tags: java, csv, jsp, servlets

When I try to export the csv file from servlet code it displayed the correct records but at the end it display extra rows.

Example: It need 1000 rows but it display 1041 rows long with 1000 records.

Below is my code and the excel sheet.

```
// for downloading csv
public void getDownloaded(String filepath, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        File file = new File(filepath);
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.getName());
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        // copy binary content to output stream
        while (in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1) {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you see genereted file  by `getCSVWrite` method on your local server directory directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a subtle bug in the `getDownloaded` method. This code here reads eventually an writes an incorrect number of bytes in case less than 4096 bytes are read, thus writing potentially garbage to the out stream:

```
//copy binary content to output stream
while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1){
    out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
}
```

It should actually use the exact number of read bytes in the write statement:

```
int length;
while ((length = in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096)) != -1) {
    out.write(outputByte, 0, length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks That helped @ gil.fernandes